# SharePoint Online Rotating Images

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to include an image carousel or rotating images on my SharePoint Online modern page, but so far I haven't found a way to do that.  Has anyone else run across this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Image Gallery webpart available out of the box on modern pages. You can use a document library full of images or just add them directly to the gallery.

In the webpart properties, choose the Carousel layout and you can even have them automatically rotate.

[image: Image Gallery webpart being edited on a modern page]

Comment: When I pick the carousel, I don't have any options with it.